# Restrict access based on HTTP_REFERER containing a string

Tags: regex, .htaccess, http-referer

I'd like to restrict access to all files in the directory on my server via `.htaccess` based on `HTTP_REFERER` for all sources except the ones containing string `wp-admin`.

Could you please provide the correct code with regex to paste into `.htaccess`?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Not a good question for here and also you don't want to do that anyway.

Comment: @pvg, why don't I want it?

Comment: because it's trivially spoofed.

Comment: i don't need a rock-solid protection, i just need some basic restriction

Comment: It isn't even that. There are saner ways to do this.

Comment: Can you please provide more details?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using mod_rewrite, and the [F] option to mark the traffic that doesn't meet the condition as forbidden. You could make the Regex statement a bit more fancy by adding ^https?:// etc., but as I have it here, only the valid traffic should pass the test. Basically, it's checking to see if HTTP_REFERER contains your domain.com/wp-admin, and if so, allows traffic as expected; otherwise, it's kicked to the curb.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# allow these referers to passthrough
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} yourdomain.com/wp-admin
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# deny everything else
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: How can I exclude the domain? I need to accept any domains, not the only one.

Comment: If it's any domain you want, allowing for a WordPress installation from any subdirectory, it would replace the line

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} yourdomain.com/wp-admin

with

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} /wp-admin

The way the RewriteCond condition works is that whatever the string the server says is the HTTP_REFERER is matched against the string that follows it, so if it's just /wp-admin that is match any time the referer URL contains that string.

Of course, this offers basically nothing in the way of security, whether or not you control the domains in question.

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't seem to work. When I'm trying to access the file from wp-admin, it gives me forbidden error.